# Why sun.misc.Unsafe#getUnsafe() can't be found using Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Once I load the class `sun.misc.Unsafe` by reflection successfully, I can't find the `getUnsafe` method as a declared method using Java reflection. Why? I have no `SecurityManager`.

This is my code, which always throws `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe", false, getClass().getClassLoader());
Assert.assertNotNull(c.getDeclaredMethod("getUnsafe"));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8, you are specifically prevented from seeing this method and other internal methods.  See the sun.reflect.Reflection class.

Under the static block of this class you can see

```
Reflection.registerMethodsToFilter(Unsafe.class, new String[]{"getUnsafe"});
```

This adds a filter for this method so it doesn't appear via reflection.

In Java 9, the intent is to make it even harder to access such internal classes.

At the moment you can still get the field directly with Java 9 build 63.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe", false, A.class.getClassLoader());
Field theUnsafe = c.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe u = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
System.out.println("u= " + u);
```

Note: you can expect this to not work in future releases.

Comment: Thanks, but just a question: If I am loading the class setting to a false load the static blocks, how is possible that the `Reflection.registerMethodsToFilter(Unsafe.class, new String[]{"getUnsafe"});` have been executed?

Comment: @rpau this class is used in many places. I would assume the class has already been loaded. Certainly by the time you ask for the methods or this registration would be broken. BTW you can't actually call this method.

Comment: BTW, therefore, I need to read the .class manually (with ASM or javasssist) to check if a given method exists?

Comment: @rpau only in very rare cases. There is about 6 methods and fields which have been blocked from view.

Comment: Is there any place where these methods are documented? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get the source for OpenJDK and search for where this API is used.  These methods are for internal use only, deliberately hidden away with the intent that they will be removed one day.  I can't imagine they would document such methods.